# Как установить SQL Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, integration-services, ssis, ssms

Мне нужно скопировать планы обслуживания.

Решил доустановить Integration Services.

Доустановил: 
[image: Установленные компоненты]

...перезагрузил, пытаюсь подключиться ... и получаю сообщение об ошибке "Класс не зарегистрирован":
[image: Ошибка при попытке подключения]

Что я сделал не так, куда бежать и как это починить? :)

Дополнение...

MS SQL установлен x64 версии.
Server Management Studio, через которую пытаюсь подключиться к Integration Services - x32 версии.

[image: Server Management Studio x32]

Возможно в этом дело?

Но не могу найти как скачать x64 версию Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Об ошибке. Начиная с SQL 2016, SSIS доступен через основное подключение к SQL Server, в дереве объектов SSMS - ветка *Integration Service Catalog*. Подключение к виду службы *Integration Services* в SSMS оставлено для совместимости со старыми версиями SSIS, где нет SSIS каталога - к примеру, SQL 2008.
Мигрировать Mantenance Plan можно следующими способами:

- Через выгрузку и последующую загрузку пакетов утилитой SSIS *dtutil*. [Подробный код](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/ssis-package-extract-from-msdb.html) и разбор вариантов для различных версий SQL. Недостаток - необходимо устанавливать SSIS, что не всегда возможно.
- Через копирование строк, выбранных запросом

`SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages 
        WHERE packagetype = 6`

с последующим открыванием mantenance plans в SSMS - параметры подключения и ссылки на базы данных переносятся некорректно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
А проект в Integration Services Catalog нужно создать?
У меня есть план обслуживания, а в Integration Services Catalog пусто (https://wampi.ru/image/6IQZ2xH).

Comment: @Евгений, откорректировал ответ именно для целей копирования планов обслуживания.